# Geomesa BBOX Query is not returning all results

Tags: hbase, geomesa

I was playing with Geomesa (using HBase) BBOX query on OSM node data. I found for a specific region geomesa is not returning all the node in the bounding box.

For example, I fired 3 queries:

1. BBOX(-122.0,47.4,-122.01,47.5)  - Output has 5,477 Unique Features
2. BBOX(-122.0,47.5,-122.01,47.6)  - Output has 9,879 Unique Features
3. BBOX(-122.0,47.4,-122.01,47.6)  - Output has 13,374 Unique Features

Looking into these bounding box I think Feature of Query 1 + Query 2 should be equal to Query 3. But actually, they are not same. The sad part is the Summation of Quer1 and Query2 has some elements which are not present in the Query 3 data itself.

Below is the image after plotting it on Kepler. Can anyone help to understand what is the issue and how to find the root cause of it?

[image: Missing points in Query 3].

**I am seeing below Exception:**

```
19/09/27 14:57:34 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=38583 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not present on S3
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FSInputStream.read(S3FSInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock.readWithExtra(HFileBlock.java:738)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$AbstractFSReader.readAtOffset(HFileBlock.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderImpl.readBlockDataInternal(HFileBlock.java:1770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderImpl.readBlockData(HFileBlock.java:1596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2.readBlock(HFileReaderV2.java:454)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlockIndex$BlockIndexReader.loadDataBlockWithScanInfo(HFileBlockIndex.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2$AbstractScannerV2.seekTo(HFileReaderV2.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2$AbstractScannerV2.seekTo(HFileReaderV2.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekAtOrAfter(StoreFileScanner.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seek(StoreFileScanner.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreScanner.seekScanners(StoreScanner.java:391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreScanner.<init>(StoreScanner.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore.getScanner(HStore.java:2208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.initializeScanners(HRegion.java:6112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.<init>(HRegion.java:6086)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.instantiateRegionScanner(HRegion.java:2841)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getScanner(HRegion.java:2821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getScanner(HRegion.java:2803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getScanner(HRegion.java:2797)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.newRegionScanner(RSRpcServices.java:2697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:3012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:36613)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:277)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an S3 consistency issue. Try running:

`emrfs sync -m <your DynamoDB catalog table> s3://<your bucket>/<your hbase root dir>`

Then re-run your query. It's very common for S3 and the DynamoDB table used to manage the S3 consistency model for HBase to get out of sync. Running this sync command as a cron job can help avoid this issue or resolve it automatically when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: give the additional information about the S3 exception, this advice no longer applies.

I would try disabling 'loose bounding boxes', as described [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/datastores/query_config.html#loose-bounding-box). If that does not resolve the discrepancy, please file a bug report on the [GeoMesa JIRA](https://geomesa.atlassian.net/browse/), ideally with reproducible steps.

Thanks,

Comment: I am seeing a similar exception as listed below. Why this exception occurs? dev.locationtech.org/mhonarc/lists/geomesa-dev/msg01027.html 

Please see the exception attached in the description? 

@emilio-lahr-vivaz

I can't provide the reproducible steps. The error is reproducible in my on of the catalog only. When I created a new catalog and load the data again then I am not seeing a similar issue in the related bounding box.